# AzureDatabrick:Error in SQL statement: package.TreeNodeException: execute, tree: Exchange hashpartitioning

Tags: azure-databricks

currently working with 2 temporary views A & B . while selecting records from individual views it gives results. But when creating  3rd view C with join of A & B it works but when we run any select query on 3rd view C it gives error  "Error in SQL statement: package.TreeNodeException: execute, tree: Exchange hashpartitioning"
Please help whats going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason could be, skewed join. i.e., the fields you are joining could have multiple combinations. This can happen mainly when the joining fields also possess null values in both the views then it could result in multiple null joined with multiple nulls.
It can be avoided by adding another possible field. Else join non null values separate and append null values from both sides.
If this does not solve the purpose, do share us some code snippet, we can try replicating and solve the issue.